# getting started with Vue native

Tags: vue.js, mobile, expo, vue-native

I've installed Vue-native-cli

Do I need to install **expo-cli** and **react-native-cli** to use build project with vue native?

I've been seeing errors like

- Expo not found and
- React, React-dom not found when I run the command

`vue-native init <projet name>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue Native has been deprecated and is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 1):

As it's written in the documentation: expo-cli or react-native-cli

> System Requirements
>
> - Globally installed node >= 6.0
> - Globally installed npm >= 4.0
> - Globally installed Expo CLI OR React Native CLI

The information above can be found [here](https://vue-native.io/docs/installation.html)

Edit: Not sure if I missunderstood `to use build project`. If you mean your project is already built (it's an APK file), then it's not needed to install the additional package. To run it, you can use android emulator, (for example BlueStacks) or transfer the app to your phone.